# Questions about frame size and how to make it not editable & how to add exit message

Tags: java, user-interface

I would like to know how to not allow the user to change the screen's size. Also, can you please explain in details how to add a confirmation message "Are you sure you want to quit the program?", because there's a file that i want to creat if the user chooses "Yes". I tried to read about it, but i didn't quiet get it. I couldn't understand where to call the method that displays the message.

```
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
     if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All operation have been saved ");
        System.exit(0);}
  }
```

Comment: Show us your code or what did you try until now?

Comment: my code is about 500 lines. do you want me to paste it all or the exit message method?

Comment: Of course the exit message .. this will make your question more clear

Answer (score 0):

Making a JFrame not resizable: `frame.setResizable(false)`
Doing something when the user closes the frame : read about the onClose listener [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

EDIT: you also need to read about Dialogs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

First detect closing window event then show yor confirmation dialog

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        Object[] options = {"Yes, please","No, thanks"};

        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,"Would you like some green eggs to go "
        + "with that ham?",
        "A Silly Question",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        options,
        options[2]);

        if(n==0){
           //Yes, please
        }else{
           //No, thanks
        }
    }
});
```

this will result the following dialog

[image]

you can see the complete documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Where do i add that. In the method i've created or in the main method?

Comment: why is the method windowClosing inside?